# How can we eliminate the extra space in the pdf when including two tex files such that they are continuous in page?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, pdf, chapters, include

I had two separate tex files ( *theory.tex* & *molecular_dynamics.tex* ) for chapter 2, where i had some written text in these tex files, and are included in a single tex file named *main.tex* whose working directory is as shown below:

On compiling this *main.tex* file, i get the end page of *theory.tex* file containing blank spaces(shown in attached screenshot) and the page of *molecular_dynamics.tex* file starts from new page (shown in attached screenshot) rather being continuous from the same page, not in next page, where the last page of *theory.tex* file ends. Is there any command that makes continuous text between these two included files? However i want the usual format when it jumps to new chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\include{packages/packages}
\begin{document}
\include{ch2/theory/theory/theory}
\include{ch2/theory/molecular_dynamics/molecular_dynamics}
\include{ch3/results1/results1}
\include{ch3/results2/results2}
\end{document}
```

[image: theory section of chapter 2]

[image: molecular dynamics section of chapter 2]

Comment: Use input. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: note that you can use `\input` instead of `\include` for your chapters (which will remove the forced page breaks) but apart from that, you should _never_ use `\include` in the preamble,  `\include{packages/packages}` is wrong and should definitely be `\input`.

Comment: @nhck yes that question's solution exactly answers my query. Thank you and Sorry for duplicate questions..